# hline in nested table

Tags: tables

I have a really complex table in my opinion which is why im running into some Problems here. I used a nested table because I had Problems when using the `\multirow` and `\cellcolor` / `\rowcolor` command. However the Problem now is that the `\hline` is not reaching to either the left and right side of the outer table. The Picture below Shows the Problem:

[image]

How can i solve this Problem? Does someone has a better solution for this Kind of table?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolor{Beige}{RGB}{219,212,192}
\definecolor{Table}{RGB}{246,244,239}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4cm}|p{6.7cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Beige}
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{B1 Eingabefelder}} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{Table}
    Nr. & Beschreibung & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}@{}}
            \multicolumn{4}{l}{Kommentare / Verhaltensweisen} \\ \hline
            H & A & B & Schweregrad \\
        \end{tabular}
    } \\ \hline
    ~ & ~ & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post complete test documents so people can test their answers. However your `\bgroup`, `\egroup` around the nested table is not doing anything replace it by `\kern-\tabcolsep\begin{tabular.....\end{tabular}\kern-\tabcolsep` to counteract the padding in the outer table cell

Comment: or simpler use `\multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}|}{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your code does not work properly. It works to the left but not to the right and the left line also disappears. What can i do?

Comment: edit your code example so it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` then it's far more likely that people will test their answers. It should have worked, did you leave a space (or newline) before the second kern, if so, don't:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The first does work only on the left side.

Comment: This is what i have tested: `\kern-\tabcolsep
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}@{}}
   \multicolumn{4}{l}{Kommentare / Verhaltensweisen} \\ \hline
   H & A & B & Schweregrad \\
  \end{tabular}
  \kern-\tabcolsep`

Comment: Even without the spaces it does not work properly...

Comment: Your example still can not be run through latex without error: don't make people have to reverse engineer the list of required packages. Please _always_ post complete documents.

Comment: This is really complex... it's part of my Bachelor Thesis and the packages are in a seperate file.

Comment: No you miss the point: we don't want to see your thesis, it is just that _you_ rather than everyone trying to help should add the 2 or 3 or 6 lines it takes so that that example runs.  You are using commands from unspecified packages (some of which I recognise as mine, but still I shouldn't have to guess, and neither should anyone else) Or better remove any commands from packages unrelated to the problem and make a simper test file that still shows the effect.

Comment: Okay i will do it now so you can test it. Stay tuned ... i really Need help

Comment: There is a test example that runs through...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to working on the contents of the table, I've had to make some informed guesses as to the likely contents of the preamble. The code below may or may not conform to your document's requirements.

Regarding the `tabular` environment, the changes I've applied can be summarized as follows:

- comment out some unneeded instructions
- add some `@{}` directives here and there
- adjust some column widths

There were some instructions, such as `\phantom{.}`, whose purpose I couldn't fathom but didn't comment out since they seem to do no harm.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4cm}|p{6.7cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Beige}
        \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{B1 Eingabefelder}} \\ 
        \hline
        %\rowcolor{Table}
        Nr. & Beschreibung & \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}|}{
            %\bgroup
                \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|
                                   >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|
                                   >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|
                                   >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}@{}}
                    \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{Kommentare / Verhaltensweisen} \\ 
                    \hline
                    H & A & B & Schweregrad \\
                \end{tabular}
           %\egroup
        } \\ 
        \hline
        \hiderowcolors
        \multirow{7}{0.4cm}{ 1} & 
        \multirow{7}{6.7cm}{Der vordefinierte Text <Pflichtfeld> behindert die Nutzer bei der Eingabe von erforderlichen Daten wie z.B. Name, Kurzeichen und UserID beim Anlegen von Personen im System. Der Inhalt der betroffenen Eingabefelder wird nicht automatisch beim Fokussieren gelöscht. Dies wird durch den Nutzer z.B. durch Markieren manuell erledigt.} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\multirow{5}{5cm}{„Ich ärgere mich jedes Mal, dass da <Pflichtfeld> vorbelegt ist.“ 
        \newline\newline 
        „Ganz blöd ist, dass ich das jetzt erst alles markieren muss.“ \phantom{.}}} \\
         & &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\
         & &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\
         & &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\
         & &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\
         & &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\ \cline{3-6}
         & &  \centering 6 & \centering 2 & \centering 3 & \centering\arraybackslash 6,57 \\ 
        \hline
        \showrowcolors
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 (you're kinder than I am, testing the result before the full MWE was posted:-)

Comment: So the rowcolor does not work right? Is there a way i can still Color the second row?

Comment: @LordTribual rowcolour should colour behind the `\multicolumn` as long as you have a recent `\colortbl` (from last year rather than last century) Note that Mico wrote this before you had posted a document that defined the colour Table, which is probably why he commented it out)

Comment: @LordTribual - I posted this answer before you provided information on how the color "Table" was defined, so I had to comment out the instruction `\rowcolor{Table}`. If you add the instruction `\definecolor{Table}{RGB}{246,244,239}` to the preamble, you can also reinstate `\rowcolor{Table}`.